# Find particular word in text file and then print the entire line

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out how input a string, search for that string in a txt file, and the print the line that contains that string. This is what I have so far

```
System.out.println("Enter Client ID");
Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
clientID = a.nextLine();


String text = "";
String line = reader.readLine();

while (line != null)
{

    if (clientID.toLowerCase().contains(line.toLowerCase())) 
    {
    text = line;
    }

    line = reader.readLine();   
}

System.out.println(text);
```

For some reason it prints out nothing.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: What is the value of `clientID` and that of `line`?  Then read out the code that you have written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
if (clientID.toLowerCase().contains(line.toLowerCase()))
```

to:

```
if (line.toLowerCase().contains(clientID.toLowerCase()))
```

Comment: You are probably correct, but how can you know without knowing the values of his variables?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the below line,

```
 if (clientID.toLowerCase().contains(line.toLowerCase()))
```

to

```
 if (line.toLowerCase().contains(clientID.toLowerCase()))
```

You need to check whether the `line` contains the `clientID` or not.